ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' for python 3.7.10
I need to use Python 3.7.10 for a project so I installed it with:
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.10

Also I installed libbfi and set the path:
brew install libffi

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"

After I was trying to install requirements.txt I got this error:
File "/Users/evr/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
WARNING: The Python ctypes extension was not compiled. Missing the libffi lib?

I have tried to:
pyenv uninstall 3.7.10

# Now reinstall with environment variables
env LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib" \
CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include" \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig" \
pyenv install 3.7.10

But I am still getting the same error:
File "/Users/evr/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
WARNING: The Python ctypes extension was not compiled. Missing the libffi lib?


You can try this which solved this problem
